# Regex doesn't replace anything before colon

Tags: c#, regex

I want to strip off the `'re:'` off subject lines in emails:

My string helper extension does the following:

```
  return Regex.Replace(value, "([re:][re :])", "",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, it seems to match on `"re :"`, but not `"re:".`
Is there any reason for this and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: You expression will match: either `r`, `e` or `:` followed by either `r`, `e`, space or `:`. I don't think you want to use character classes here. It looks more like you want `re ?:` but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean something like:

```
Regex.Replace(value, "re:|re :", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Which can also be written as:

```
Regex.Replace(value, "re ?:", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And here is a possibly better expression:

```
Regex.Replace(value, "^\s*re\s*:\s*", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Which only matches at the beginning of the string (`^`) and also removes any following spaces (`\s*`).

Comment: All seem to pass my unit tests, I like the first as its very readable, but I need to use Trim() on the resulting string.